# No module named urls

Tags: python, django

I'm following the Django Tutorials, I'm at the end of part 3, at Decoupling the URLconfs, at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial03/#intro-tutorial03 and I'm getting a "No module named urls" error message.

When I change:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('mysite.polls.views',
    (r'^polls/$', 'index'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

to:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/', include('mysite.polls.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I changed `include('mysite.polls.urls')),` to `include(mysite.polls.urls)),`, but it still didn't work.

How to solve this problem?

UPDATE 2: at mysite/polls/urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('mysite.polls.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),
)
```

UPDATE 4: the whole project is at

http://www.mediafire.com/?t1jvomjgjz1

Comment: You could try posting the error message to a pastebin site and then linking to it here. That could help a lot.

Comment: Also, can you post the contents of `mysite/polls/urls.py`?

Comment: the contents of `mysite/polls/urls.py` have just been posted

Comment: Just double-check that it's actually named `urls.py`. I've mis-typed things to many times to count and spent hours refactoring code before I thought to check the filename.

Comment: From all of the information you've provided so far, the import shouldn't be failing. Can you try importing from the shell? Run "manage.py shell", then once it is running, enter "from mysite.polls import urls". Did you get the same ImportError?

Comment: I did not get the same import error. I did not get an error at all.

Comment: It shouldn't be failing. Can you zip up your Django tutorial project and post it online somewhere for us to download and look at? Maybe it's something specific to your workstation (kind of the opposite of "works on my machine").

Comment: Lance, as you requested, I updated the question with a link to the whole project.

Comment: Strange, just tested it on my machine. It runs fine, and then I try to access `http://localhost:8000/polls/`, and it complains it can't find a match, so it must have imported `mysite.polls.urls` properly. I did have to remove all the `polls` prefixes to the URLs in the file so that it matched the url. After that it just gives a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

Changes to `mysite/polls/urls.py` @ http://dpaste.com/166242/. Changes to `mysite/urls.py` @ http://dpaste.com/166243/

That's with:
OS X 10.6.2
Python 2.6.3 (built from source)
Django Version 1.1.1

Comment: @David - It did exactly the same on my machine. :\

Comment: It was 1:35AM and I had to go to sleep, but I'm back now. Hello!

Comment: Does anybody have the final code from the official Django tutorial?

Comment: oh, men... I was looking at the polls directory and the urls.py inside it and thinking it was mysite/polls/urls.py, but I was actually looking at deltrem/mytemplates/polls/urls.py and editing it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't re-produce the import error on my machine using your project files (Windows 7, Django 1.1.1, Python 2.6.4). Everything imported fine but the urls were not specified properly (like the tutorial shows). Fixing the code:

/mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/', include('mysite.polls.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

/mysite/polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('mysite.polls.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
    (r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),
)
```

Visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ - I received a TemplateDoesNotExist exception because the template file is missing.

**I'm afraid my answer might be to reboot and try it again. ;)**

Comment: If he's using WSGI or something.... Django likes to super-cache the heck out of everything... I ran into so many headaches with that when I first started developing with Django..... dev server saves a lot of pain.

Comment: @Mark - He's going through the tutorial so I can't imagine setting up WSGI to serve it. Plus his SERVER_SOFTWARE (screenshot 3) is set to "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.6.4", which matches what my machine serves when using the dev server.

Comment: I was just like you said, "the urls were not specified properly (like the tutorial shows)", they really weren't.

Comment: Oh I figured.... but I was just sayin' ;) I tried developing on a live server. Not good.

Answer (score 52):

I had a similar problem in my project root ... django complained that it couldn't find the module mysite.urls.

Turns out my ROOT_URLCONF variable in settings.py, which was set up using the default values, was set incorrect. Instead of "mysite.urls", it should have been simply "urls"

I changed it, and voila, it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was my exact problem as well. Could it have something to do with me using a different settings module setup? (settings/development.py, settings/production.py)

Comment: I discovered this issue is from me following [Zachary Voase's project structure](http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2010/02/03/django-project-conventions/). Since it requires using `django-admin.py` and not `manage.py`, my site isn't in sys.path, and I had added the *project* package to path and not its parent directory. Once I amended `PYTHONPATH` from `/path/to/site/project` to `/path/to/site`, I was able to use the default `ROOT_URLCONF` and just had to change `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.deployment` to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.deployment`.

Comment: Looks like ROOT_URLCONF is the sole place that contains the name of the root module, so if you rename your project then it will break.

Comment: For me it worked the other way round. So  had to replace 'urls' with 'mysite.urls' and viola, it worked :)

Answer (score 8):

Is there an `__init__.py` inside mysite/polls/ directory?

Comment: Empty is fine, that just tells Python the directory is a package.  Make sure there's an `__init__.py` in the parent `mysite` directory too

Comment: There is too and by the way it's empty too.

Comment: I'm going to assume there is one. If Delirium is following the Django tutorial, he probably used the `djangoadmin.py`/`manage.py` commands to create the site and app. They place the `__init__.py` in there by default. As far as I can tell, Delirium has had a working site, using the `polls` module, up until he tried decoupling the URLConf from the site and placing it in the app. This seems to indicate that there's an issue as to the placement of the `urls.py` file and how it's called.

Comment: I've a question and a suggestion (that fix the problem).

Question: why can't you just use include('mysite.pools.urls') ?
Suggestion: You can try to import mysite.pools.urls before, i.e "from mysite.pools import urls as pool_urls" and use "include(pool_urls)"

Comment: chromano, what is the difference if import mysite.polls.urls before? by the way, it's really polls. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polls

Comment: I would second trying to import it. To add on to that, you can use `python manage.py shell` to open a django terminal shell and then try `from mysite.polls import urls`. If you can import it, than the problem is definitely something in the syntax of `mysite/urls.py`.

Comment: @David - according to his answer to my comment on the main question, he doesn't get an error when importing the urls from the shell.

Comment: @delirium-tremens sorry about the mistake. In python you just can't import a module name and refer to others modules imported by it, i.e, you can't do `import site` and use `site.polls.urls`, you should import `site.polls.urls` module, eg: `import site.polls.urls` and then use `site.polls.urls`, got it? btw, is it working now?

Answer (score 5):

I also had a weird problem with "No module named mysite.urls".
The admin site was down and the my whole site.

The solution, after a few hours of searching the web, was on my side : Django is caching some of the settings in a file that he knows from an environment variable.

I just closed my terminal in which i was doing the runnserver thing and opened a new one.

Comment: Thank you, I would never have thought of that!

Comment: Thanks! When running django via IIS: restarting the IIS server is the equivalent action for closing-opening the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly the same thing.  Python newbie mistake by reading ahead.  I created a file call "polls.url" thinking it was some sort of special django template file.

I misunderstood the text:
"Now that we've decoupled that, we need to decouple the polls.urls URLconf by removing the leading "polls/" from each line, and removing the lines registering the admin site. Your polls.urls file should now look like this:
"

It should really read:
"Now that we've decoupled that, we need to decouple the polls.urls URLconf by removing the leading "polls/" from each line, and removing the lines registering the admin site. Your polls/urls.py file should now look like this:
"

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I fixed my problem by correcting a typo inside settings.py INSTALLED_APPS. I had 'webbapp' instead of 'webapp' so you might want to check on that as well (for people still having the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Like Ryan Bagwell, problem was (at least temporarily) solved by changing  ROOT_URLCONF in myproject/myproject/settings.py. 
I had to add "myproject" to ROOT_URLCONF to have there this:
"%s.myproject.urls" % PROJECT_APP