# Import Error While Executing Django Tutorial

Tags: python, django

I am following Django tutorial given in the following link:-

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

While running server I get many error messages:-

```
ImportError at /admin/

No module named polls.urls

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:        http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.4.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named polls.urls

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:      C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:         2.7.3

Python Path:    

['D:\\chetan\\All_My_Projects\\mysite1',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

The errors are similar to what has been asked in:-

[No module named urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353416/no-module-named-urls)

My question is, **do we need to add the project directory,which in my case would be D:\chetan\All_My_Projects\mysite1 to environment variable?** Is this causing the problem..

Comment: is ``polls`` added in ``INSTALLED_APPS`` inside ``settings.py``?

Comment: As far as I see.. there is no `urls.py` in polls. its at `mysite/urls.py`

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in your `mysite1` directory?

Comment: @Surya: urls.py is present in both mysite1 and polls app

Comment: @Rohan: __init__.py is present in mysite1 directory

Comment: @Chetan No. If you create an app `python manage.py startapp ..` *It doesn't give you `urls.py`** Please check `settings.py` for `ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'`. That's the location of your urls.

Comment: Check the tutorial again. It never mentioned that there is `urls.py` in polls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the whole Django Project ( I suppose, you are on Windows, using Py 27 )

Follow these steps:

- open cmd, direct it to `d:\`, Now `python c:/python27/lib/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject mysite`
- `cd mysite` and `python manage.py startapp polls`

Now, `cd polls`

```
# polls/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def polls_home(request):
    return render_to_response("polls.html")

# polls/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import views
urlpatterns = patterns ("",
                            url(r'^polls$', views.polls_home),
)
```

- Go to d:/mysite/mysite/settings.py and add `polls` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
- *very important*: open mysite/mysite/urls.py

add `url(r'^home$', include('polls.urls') ),` to url patterns

Now, runserver and open `/home/polls`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have typed in `<your_app>/urls.py`:

```
url(r'^polls/', include(polls.urls))
```

Instead of this? (the quotes are needed):

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))
```

I would check if `polls` is in `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `<your_app>/settings.py` if that doesn't work.

Comment: polls is added in installed apps..everything runs fine till part 2 of the tutorial until i reach part 3 which is decoupling of the url's

Comment: have you checked ``urls.py``?

Comment: I have the single quotes as you suggested above.I shall remove them and have a go again..

Comment: that looks fine, but the main ``urls.py`` (the one inside the main app folder) is including ``polls.urls`` with the quotes?

Comment: The quotes are needed, sorry if I didn't make myself clear. If you are already using ``include('polls.urls')`` I don't know what could be failing. Are you doing some explicit ``import polls.urls`` somewhere?

Comment: i get 'undefined variable polls' after removing the single quotes.

Comment: I reverted the changes. Just to add to the question above, i get 'unresolved import errors' in urls.py,admin.py,views.py whenever i add the lines(from polls.models import Poll,from polls.models import Choice)...i think this has the clue to my problem but i am not able to solve it..

Comment: Humm. See my edit, I've added a, hopefully useful, link to another SO question.

Comment: Referred to the link you pasted above. Even i included it in my question as 'No module named urls'...still not working out..

Comment: Sorry, removed :( my fault. I'm sorry I can't help you further.

Comment: My import errors have gone.I added my project 'mysite1' to the PythoPath which removed the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Django tutorial executed properly after adding my project in PythonPath.i.e, my project was created in 'D:\chetan\All_My_Projects\mysite1'. All i had to do in Aptana Studio is:-

1.Go to Windows->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter-Python

2.Add 'D:\chetan\All_My_Projects\mysite1' to the PythonPath.

Thank you all for your help. I would also like to refer to the following link which has emphasized on adding the project to the PythonPath:-

http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/Install_Django_and_Build_Your_First_App

Comment: you don't have to manually put the app in python path. django takes care of that!!

Comment: @Surya: i only included the main Project to the python path...not the app 'polls'..

Comment: you don't have to do that!! I wrote a detailed answer to this question. Please check it.. did I ever mentioned including it in python path?? NO! when you do `django manage.py runserver` it automatically does

Comment: @Surya: agree to what you suggest...django documentation for manage.py mentions the same...

Comment: I don't know why you are doing these things.. its simply not required. Actually, I can't say for sure but... these small things might sit on our head when it comes to deployment. But if your are comfortable with your config. carry on. i don't have anything to say more.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial could benefit from using absolute paths, e.g.  `mysite/mysite/urls.py`, etc. to avoid confusion.  This is why...

The django tutorial is a bit confusing because it creates a project `mysite` (which most of us are going to give a different name) and then within that project `mysite` it also has a site called `mysite`.

- One `mysite` directory is used for starting the server because it contains `manage.py`
- The other nested `mysite` contains the `urls.py` which maps to the new app (the tutorial calls this app `polls`).

So although the tutorial clearly explains what the directory structure **should** look like, if one tries to follow it too quickly it's not immediately obvious that the app `polls` is supposed to reside side-by-side the site `mysite`).  thus creating `mysite/mysite`, `mysite/polls` or perhaps `djangotest/djangotest`, `djangotest/myapp`, etc.

When following this tutorial, if one had created the necessary files inside the wrong directory, it won't be immediately obvious what that person had done wrong resulting in the error `No module named polls.urls`.